# QWebElement evaluateJavaScript this.click() method don't work

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, qwebview, qwebelement

I have the HTML form in QWebView loaded. This HTML has following two elements:

```
    <button class="submit1" tabindex="1" type="submit" id="submit1">accept</button>
    <button class="submit2" tabindex="2" type="submit" id="submit2">decline</button>
```

In code I have follwing:

```
    QWebView webView;
    ...
    QWebElement button = webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("button[id=\"submit1\"]");
    button.evaluateJavaScript("this.click();");
```

And this last line of code don't work for me.
Moreover if I have an  element instead of button - JavaScript click() method works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the question per-say as its really hard to tell from the info you gave us what is the EXACT problem, but what I can do is give you some guidelines on debugging problems in QWebView.

1) First thing I would check, is if you actually have the button element in hand. try to do this:

```
QWebView webView;
...
QWebElement button = webView->page()....findFirst("button[id=\"submit1\"]");
if button is not None:
    button.evaluateJavaScript("this.click();");
else:
    print "Oh dear!"
```

By this we wanna see if findFirst() actually gets the elements (I believe it does, syntax seems to be fine).

2) Go to the web page you're working on. Does that button actually work? some script might inject a 'disabled' attribute to it, which renders it un-clickable.

3) Try to lock in on the element in some different way:

get it by class:

```
QWebElement button = webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("button[class=submit1]");
```

Try to lock in on the parent, then get the 1st child:

```
QWebElement parent = **get the parent element**
button = parent.findAll("button")[0]
```

Usually I try to avoid using methods like this one, as it is susceptible to crashing in several cases. If this is the only thing working for you, I strongly recommend some 'try\except' to avoid any problems.

> small note: you said that if u get an element instead of a button, click() works fine. the reason is that click() does nothing to an
>   element that isn't clickable or has some kind of behavior attached to
>   the click() event. So its working by basically doing nothing :)